# MySql privilege error while importing table from mySql to hive

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop

I have a table author with schema (name varchar(20),address varchar(20) in MySql. I want to import the table to hive using sqoop.

Steps followed for this -

1. Database creation test1
2. Table creation and insertion of rows in author table
3. Grant privileges by

   ```
   grant all on *.* to  ‘root’@’localhost’ with grant option;
   flush privileges;"
   ```
4. Sqoop import

   ```
    sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1 --table author --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table author_MySQL -m 1
   ```

On trying to do sqoop import I am getting the error :

> ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: **Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'test1'**java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'test1'
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.getColumnNames(CatalogQueryManager.java:162)

I am a Hadoop beginner. I have referred the tutorial at this link :https://acadgild.com/blog/how-to-import-data-from-mysql-to-hive-using-sqoop/ for hive import. But I am getting the above error for MYSQL privilege.

MySql version used :5.7.17 for Ubuntu

Can you help me find out how to set the MYSQL privilege so that sqoop import is successful ?